# Is it somehow possible to give a class a different filename in Java with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, filenames, classname

As the title already says, I would like to know if it is somehow possible to give a class a different filename in Java with Eclipse ?

Edit: I only want to know if its possible with Eclipse. If you don't know the answer, please resist the urge to respond with condescending answers.

Edit2: It's hilarious what kind of responses I get here. All I wanted to know is if it is possible to have a class with a different filename (and I meant the public class) and nothing else. I thought this is the kind of forum to ask these questions, but the second response I got was already an insult. Is this some kind of taboo question or what is going on ?

Comment: You mean, like having `Class A` declared in a file `Class B.java`? Apart from inner classes and the like, I'm not sure if you could (or why you would) do that.

Comment: *"As the title already says.."*  What neither the title nor body of the question says, is why you'd want to do such a silly thing (presuming Marcelo described it accurately - the question was a bit vague).

Comment: What is your reason doing that?

Comment: Re: Your edit. Press F2 in Eclipse to rename the file. Try build your project and watch the compiler throw errors. I'm not trying to be condescending, Java is how it is - the JLS specifies that you shouldn't do it; the compilers force you to not do it.

Comment: `If you don't know the answer, please resist the urge to respond with condescending answers.`. We don't like your condescending tone either.

Comment: *"What's going on"*  is that you didn't specify your question clearly, and assumed everyone had to know what you want - which, given the interpretation most had, is kind of a weird thing to do.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case then mea culpa, next time I will be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would like to do that but it is possible if you compile files from command line with help of symbolic links.

Let's say you have `class YourClass` saved in a file `OtherName.java`. If you create a symbolic link to that file like this:

**UNIX system:** (for sure doesn't work on Solaris - other system aren't verified)

```
ln -s OtherName.java YourClass.java
javac YourClass.java
```

**WINDOWS system:** (works on Windows Vista/2008+)

```
mklink YourClass.java OtherName.java
javac YourClass.java
```

the compiler finds the type and compilation works...

---

This solution is not verified on Unix systems, but works for sure on Windows Vista/2008+..

Comment: @Primosk on solaris compilation works fine ,runtime error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test1

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman, if I understand right, you created `class Test1` and save it into Test.java. Then you created symbolic link Test1.java to Test.java and tried to run `javac Test1.java' and it failed? If that is so, I will correct the answer....

Answer (score 7):

Your filename should always match your class name, end of story. Although the JLS doesn't specifically state that it HAS to be done, they leave it up to the implementation of the compiler to make that decision. I'm pretty sure most (if not all) will not allow you to differ from that standard.

[The JLS states:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/packages.doc.html#26783)

> When packages are stored in a file system (§7.2.1), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).
>
> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per compilation unit. This restriction makes it easy for a compiler for the Java programming language or an implementation of the Java virtual machine to find a named class within a package; for example, the source code for a public type wet.sprocket.Toad would be found in a file Toad.java in the directory wet/sprocket, and the corresponding object code would be found in the file Toad.class in the same directory.

So while you may be able to rename the file itself in eclipse, or your filesystem - you will more than likely hit a compile error.

Comment: However, the way I see it, if you take the eclipse compiler and remove the filename check the class will compile and run just fine. Is that correct?

Comment: I think it might be open to interpretation. I just read the Java spec and it does refer to "a type" and not to "only one type" or something like that: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.6 "7.6 Top Level Type Declarations - By default, the top level types declared in a package are accessible only within the compilation units of that package, but a type may be declared to be public to grant access to the type from code in other packages (§6.6, §8.1.1, §9.1.1)." I also didn't see all that much concerning the file name but I might have missed that.

Comment: I've copied the relevant part in my answer. If you read a few paragraphs down from the link I put, and you have also put (unfortunately I can't link directly to the paragraph in question). What it basically says is: it tries to find the name of the class that matches the name of the package on the file system (e.g. MyClass in the MyClass.java file) and it is up to the compiler to enfore that as a compile-time error if it can't find it. If you can find a compiler that doesn't do that - then by all means use it. Nothing here is open to intepretation.

Comment: I disagree. "the host system may choose" is definitely open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

What does Eclipse have with the naming conventions or rules of Java Programming Language?
Eclipse is just an IDE, and if you are working with Java you have to obey **its rules.**

Lets's say you have `X.java` file. This means that you can have only one `public / abstract / final class named X` in this file. There is no limitation on the number of classes and their names and also their nesting relations with each other **as far as no more than one class** holds the filename as its class name. If a class takes the filename, then it should have one or more of these modifiers: `public, static, final.` That's the story.

Comment: Another poster posted that its no definite Java rule so you are wrong in that regard (or he is) and its merely an Eclipse thing. And if there is a possibility to change that behaviour in Eclipse is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I'm not wrong on this subject, try some naming classes in your code and see the results.

Comment: No, what I meant was that you said its a Java rule. He says its a compiler thing. So which is it ?

Comment: How does compiler work? It works based on Java conventions of course.

Comment: Then please show me where the specs say that. I found nothing but only ambiguous statements regarding that topic.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Java a public class and the file must have the same name.

If you try to give the class another name, the compiler will fail with

```
class YourClass is public, should be declared in a file named YourClass.java
```

But you can declare additional private classes in a file which contains a public class.

Answer (score 1):

below are the situations where you can have different class name.

1.class is not public class and exists in a java file where atleast one  public class is defined

```
class notpublic{

}
public class PublicClass {

}
```

2.Class is a InnerClass .

```
public class PublicClass {

        class InnerClass{

        }
    }
```